# A good measure theoretic probability textbook for self study

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

I know this is probably asked many times, but my request may be a bit specific.

I am starting my PhD in statistics soon and I want to start preparing for the comprehensive exams right now. My school uses Durrett's classic for the graduate probability courses and it is also one of the recommended books in the comprehensive exam reading list. So I tried to start reading it on my own. But unfortunately, I cannot get through it at all. It is really terse and it is not really written in a natural order for statistis students. (For example, expectation was introduced way before convergence of random variables and Borel-Cantelli lemma.) Furthermore, it is really difficult to grasp the motivation for why certain theorems are introduced.

So I switched to Rosenthal's "A first look at rigorous probability theory" which is also in the recommended list. It feels much better. I can get through materials and know why each theorem and lemma is needed. But the big issue is, it covers much fewer materials than Durrett and sometimes feels a little bit too introductory for PhD students and comprehensive exams.

So my request is does anyone know a good textbook that is in between these two? One that is comprehensive enough but also easy to read? Thank you very much!!

**P.S.**
I should point out that by easy, I didn't mean it would be a breeze. If it is, I am not learning anything. It's just the learning curve for Durrett feels too steep for me and it is becoming counter-productive. TBH, many of my classmates are saying Durrett was horribly written, albeit extremely comprehensive. Need to point out that many of us are not well-trained in pure math. There is also one who came from pure math says he doesn't like how Durrett was written and just gave up reading it and the only thing he uses it for is the practice questions.

Comment: IMHO any book with a proof of the Radon-Nykodim theorem will be not as easy to read, and definitively you will need this essential theorem for measure theoretic probability theory. Durrett indeed is easier than many other books like the book of Ash or Klenke, so I dont think that there isn't a book like you want

Comment: Rosenthal has Radon-Nykodim as well. I didn't reach that part yet. As of now, I wouldn't say I am gliding through it, but I'm definitely making progress and actually learning stuff and letting them sink in. But while reading Durrett, I can get stuck at one page for hours and don't understand why the material is there. So materials don't register well at all and I feel very counter-productive and demotivated.